# How to resolve problem with unique id PHP, ORACLE 12C

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Using PHP + Oracle 12c

I'm trying to insert many rows but i got an error `"oci_execute(): ORA-00001: unique constraint (S95417.FIRMA__IDX)"` This is strange for me because in loop i'm getting  last id and incrementing it.

I used debbuger and (On INSERT) i'm getting last id but incrementing is not working.
Could you tell me why?

Data which i added

```
INSERT INTO FIRMA VALUES(18,MICROSOFT,2432213715,2020-03-26,23)
INSERT INTO FIRMA VALUES(19,APPLE,7512202082,2020-03-26,42)





SELECT NVL(MAX(firmaid),0)+1
```

I made code very similar using that for other tables and it's working fine.

My code:

```
  $ile_razy = $_POST['liczba_powtorzen'];

    $firma = "SELECT * FROM FIRMA";

    $c = oci_connect($username, $password, $database);
    if (!$c) {
        $m = oci_error();
        trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
    }

        $file = 'firma.txt';
        $current = file_get_contents($file);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ile_razy; $i++) {

        $nazwa = randCompanyName();
        $nip = randNIP();
        $dataWspolpracy = date("Y-m-d");

        $ids_array = array();

        $adresid = "SELECT adresid FROM ADRES";

        $stmtt = oci_parse($c, $adresid);

        $result = oci_execute($stmtt);

        while($row = oci_fetch_array($stmtt))
        {
            $ids_array[] = $row['ADRESID'];
        }
        $randIndex = array_rand($ids_array);
        $adresId = $ids_array[$randIndex];

    // HERE IS PROBLEM
        $firmaQuery = "INSERT INTO FIRMA SELECT NVL(MAX(firmaid),0) + 1,'$nazwa', '$nip', '$dataWspolpracy', '$adresId' from FIRMA";
        $ex = oci_parse($c,$firmaQuery);
// "zapytanie" is working fine
        $zapytanie = "SELECT NVL(MAX(firmaid),0)+1 from FIRMA";
        $stmt = oci_parse($c, $zapytanie);
        $results = oci_execute($stmt);
        while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
            $rowid  = $row["NVL(MAX(FIRMAID),0)+1"];  
        }
        $firmaIdForTxt = "INSERT INTO FIRMA VALUES(".$rowid.",".$nazwa.",".$nip.",".$dataWspolpracy.",".$adresId.")";
        echo $rowid. ", ";
        oci_execute($ex);
        $current .= $i. ".".$firmaIdForTxt."\n";
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
        }
```

[image]

In my db
[image]

I have changed that but error still appears

[image]

Comment: @Joffrey's answer is the best approach for this cases but if you want to keep it this way then you should edit the question and add the data from the table so we can debug it.

Comment: @ErgiNushi what do you mean 'add the data from the table'?

Comment: So that we have a better insight on what is on your table causing the error so we can replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `FIRMAID` an [identity column](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-identity-column/) : Oracle will handle the increment internally, and it is much more safer for your data.

Then you can insert your data with this query :

```
INSERT INTO FIRMA(nazwa, nip, datawspolpracy, adresid) VALUES('$nazwa', '$nip', '$dataWspolpracy', '$adresId')
```

NOTE : this is for a quick answer, for a safer solution and avoid SQL injections, use prepared statements : [PHP oci examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.examples.php) (See example #2)

Comment: I have changed that into firmaid NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, but error with unique constraint still appears..

Comment: What are the constraints of your table ?

Comment: I didn't set anything i have just edited post and added create table "FIRMY"

Comment: Ok, it makes more sense now. The problem is not related to the auto-increment : the error tells you that you break the rule `FIRMA__ID` : you declare `adres_adresid` as `UNIQUE`, but somehow you try to insert (at least)  two different rows with the same value for `adres_adresid` . Either you have problems in your data, either this data definition is not correct for your application.

Comment: This can't be problem with adres id (fk) because generated data by function looks good. I see that in debbuger and test file. This is something wrong with primary key..